# change google.maps.DirectionsResult programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When using the [google.maps.DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsService) class, passing some waypoints to its request, one will get a google.maps.DirectionsResult object which, in turn, can be displayed on the map using the [google.maps.DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsRenderer) class.

The specified waypoints will appear, by default, as markers labeled A,B,C and so on...

If the DirectionsRenderer is configured to be draggable, dragging those waypoint markers will in turn trigger `directions_changed` on the DirectionsRenderer, populate its `dragResult` property, and ultimately change the underlying route. This change propagates to every related object including the instructions panel if you are displaying it.

The aforementioned behavior [is shown in this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable).

**I can't figure out how to simulate this drag action programmatically**. I've tried manipulating the DirectionsResult object and calling the `setDirections` method of the DirectionsRenderer object, but this manipulation often leads to inconsistent routes.

For example, sometimes one of my waypoints falls on a dead end.

[image: Waypoint on dead end]

After getting my DirectionsResult object I iterate on each of its legs. If the angle between

1. the last step of a given leg and
2. the first step of the next leg

is close to 180° it means I have to turn back, so I want to change that waypoint to the next suitable location. I'm doing it this way:

```
var computeHeading=function(location1,location2) {
    return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(location1,location2);
};

var legsArray = DirectionsResult.routes[0].legs;
for (var legIndex = 0; legIndex < legsArray.length - 1; legIndex++) {
    // Current leg
    var DirectionsLeg = legsArray[legIndex];

    // Last Step of current Leg
    var lastDirectionsStep = DirectionsLeg.steps.slice(-1)[0];

    // Next Leg
    var nextDirectionsLeg = legsArray[legIndex + 1];

    // First step of Next Leg
    var nextDirectionsStep = nextDirectionsLeg.steps[0];

    var lastHeading = computeHeading(lastDirectionsStep.start_location, lastDirectionsStep.end_location);
    var nextHeading = computeHeading(nextDirectionsStep.start_location, nextDirectionsStep.end_location);
    var theAngle = Math.abs(nextHeading-lastHeading);

    // Arbitrary threshold. If the angle is over 170 it's a deadend
    if(theAngle>170) {
        DirectionsLeg.steps.pop();
        DirectionsLeg.end_location = DirectionsLeg.steps.slice(-1)[0].end_location;

        nextDirectionsLeg.steps = nextDirectionsLeg.steps.slice(1);
        nextDirectionsLeg.start_location =nextDirectionsLeg.steps[0].start_location;
    }
}
```

It turns out that the second to last location of leg 0 doesn't always match the second location of leg 1, so **I generate an unwanted gap between the route legs**. This doesn't happen when manually dragging the waypoint marker: it manages to keep the route continuity.

Comment: @geocodezip I added my code. Care to remove the downvote :/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turn out that dragging the marker triggers one or more calls to the Directions API, which is what I was trying to avoid for the sake of economy. So I figured that, after trimming legs from the original DirectionsResult, I should redefine the waypoints and request a new route.

```
var optimizeRoute=function(DirectionsResult) {

    var computeHeading=function(location1,location2) {
        return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(location1,location2);
    };

    var legsArray = DirectionsResult.routes[0].legs;
    for (var legIndex = 0; legIndex < legsArray.length - 1; legIndex++) {
        // Current leg
        var DirectionsLeg = legsArray[legIndex];

        // Last Step of current Leg
        var lastDirectionsStep = DirectionsLeg.steps.slice(-1)[0];

        // Next Leg
        var nextDirectionsLeg = legsArray[legIndex + 1];

        // First step of Next Leg
        var nextDirectionsStep = nextDirectionsLeg.steps[0];

        var lastHeading = computeHeading(lastDirectionsStep.start_location, lastDirectionsStep.end_location);
        var nextHeading = computeHeading(nextDirectionsStep.start_location, nextDirectionsStep.end_location);
        var theAngle = Math.abs(nextHeading-lastHeading);

        // Arbitrary threshold. If the angle is over 170 it's a deadend
        if(theAngle>170 && theAngle<190) {
            DirectionsLeg.steps.pop();
            DirectionsLeg.end_location = DirectionsLeg.steps.slice(-1)[0].end_location;
            DirectionsResult.request.waypoints[legIndex].location = DirectionsLeg.end_location;
            DirectionsResult.needsReroute = true;
        }
    }

    return DirectionsResult;
}
```

After that, if the "optimized" DirectionsResult has the property "needReroute" set to true, I make a new call to the google.maps.DirectionsService class, this time using the first DirectionsResult.request as my modified request.

So, let's say I have this function that takes a request and callbacks a DirectionsResult:

```
var getRoute=function(myRequest,callback) {

   var DirectionsService=new google.maps.DirectionsService();

   DirectionsService.route(myRequest, function(DirectionsResult, status) {

    if(status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

         var optimizedDirectionsResult=optimizeRoute(DirectionsResult);

         if(optimizedDirectionsResult.needsReroute) {
             getRoute(optimizedDirectionsResult.request, callback);
         } else {
             callback(optimizedDirectionsResult);
         }

     } else {
       console.warn('failed',status);
       callback(null);
     }

   });

};
```